# Display column names and records from table in a JSP Page

Tags: html, jsp, resultset

I know this question may be asked in many different ways, but i am kind of stuck in the code where i cannot display the column names along with the records. I am getting records displayed but not the column names. Any help appreciated, my code so far is below -

```html
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
   ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData();
   int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
   
  while(resultSet.next())
  {
  %>
  <tr>
  <%
  ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i=1; i<=count;i++)
   { 
       String name = metadata.getColumnName(i);
    columns.add(name);
     %>
    <td>
    <%= resultSet.getString(i)%>
    
                </td>
                <% 
             }
                %>                   
             </tr>
        
  <%
  }
  
  connection.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  %>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Modified code with @swati suggestion. I have added table before try and included the array and for loop in the try. This is throwing syntax and constructor error

```html
<table style="width:100%;text-align:left;border-collapse:collapse;background-color:gold;" border="2" bordercolor="Blue">
  <tr style="background-color:yellowgreen;color:white;">
  </tr>
  <%
  try{
   Connection connection = null;
   ResultSet resultSet = null;
   int counter=1;
   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@DEV:1521:DEV","DEV","DEV");
   Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
   String sql = ("SELECT * FROM tblnm");
   resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
   ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData();
   int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
   ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<>(); 
    <table>
    <tr> //row for displaying column names
        <%for(int i=1; i<=count;i++)
            { 
             String name = metadata.getColumnName(i);
             columns.add(name);      
        %>
          <td><%=name%></td> //displaying column name
        <% } %>
    </tr>
     <%
      while(resultSet.next())
        {
     %>
    <tr>  
        //looping through names      
         <% for(int i=1;i<columns.size();i++) { %>
          //get values from particular columns  
            <td><%= resultSet.getString(columns.get(i))%></td>
         <% } %> //closing for loop
    </tr>
       <%
        }
      
      connection.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
      %>
      </table>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table structure is wrong .You need to display all column name first then all rows under columns currently your code doesn't show any column name because you are not writng any code to do the same.Instead your code should look like below :

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
 ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData();
 int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
 ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<>(); 
    <table>
    <tr> //row for displaying column names
        <%for(int i=1; i<=count;i++)
            { 
             String name = metadata.getColumnName(i);
             columns.add(name);      
        %>
          <td><%=name%></td> //displaying column name
        <% } %>
    </tr>
     <%
      while(resultSet.next())
        {
     %>
    <tr>  
        //looping through names      
         <% for(int i=1;i<columns.size();i++) { %>
          //get values from particular columns  
            <td><%= resultSet.getString(columns.get(i))%></td>
         <% } %> //closing for loop
    </tr>
       <%
        } //closing while loop 
       //other codes put here
       %>
  </table>
```

Comment: I already have a table defined before try {. When i add your code, its throwing error. I have edited my original post to include the modified code.

Comment: First check if the column names are displaying correctly or not ..comment out whole `for loop` which is inside `while(resultSet.next())` and also check if `arraylist` is having required values or not.

Comment: No columns are getting displayed. Arrray list is getting populated with column names though

Comment: that's not possible , because if arraylist is populating then why column name doesn't display because we are displaying same under `for loop` i am confuse :) now

Comment: Can you check the modified code above...i have included Table inside TRY block that is throwing error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215595/discussion-between-swati-and-arun-k).